# Unity3D cannot open Assets from Web page

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, ubuntu, unity-game-engine

I have installed Unity3D 5.1.0f3 Personal on Ubuntu. I have not installed Wine for Ubuntu.
When I tried to open link: Open in Unity, on the page https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/25794. I've got error:

```
The address wasn't understood

Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because one of the 
following protocols (com.unity3d.kharma) isn't associated with any
program or is not allowed in this context.

You might need to install other software to open this address.
```

Can someone help me to resolve the problem. My browsers are Firefox and Chrome.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can open a project (new if necessary) and import the asset using the Unity editor.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked to me but you had to do the following.
1. Open a new project and then click on the window option from the main toolbar. 
2. Select the option Asset store (CTRL+9) and then you should be able to see the unity asset in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Unity3D is beta in Linux, does not work the schema to store.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, but you should be able to get around this by opening the Asset Store in the Unity editor and downloading the asset from there

Answer (score 0):

1.5 years later. I'm using Unity on Linux as well. The protocol is still not understood, but there's no Asset Store in Unity itself either (Window » Asset Store button does nothing). Unity will not recognise that here's a Unity Hub installed, even though it was installed by Unity Hub, and the My Assets window therefore only ever shows an error. It seems there's no way to get Assets into Unity on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a newer version of Unity, you can click `Add to My assets` on Browser Asset Store then install them via the Package Manager.

Open a New or Existing Project -> Window -> Package Manager, then by selecting "My Assets" in the source drop down will show all assets that you have added on the browser.